# C++: Initializing member Vector values

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, initialization

I'm new to C++. I know it's always better to use initialization list to initialize member variables, instead of doing it within the constructor body...

For instance,

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(int Value) : m_Value(Value) { }
private:
    int m_Value;
}
```

is better than

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass(int Value) { 
        m_Value = Value;
    }
private:
    int m_Value;
}
```

, since the latter initializes the variable twice..

However,  I was wondering what I should do when initializing a member vector..

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass();
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_StringVector;
}
```

I want to initialize the values in my member vector GIVEN THAT the contents of the vector are Always the Same (constant) regardless of instances..

For example, I know that member vector named "signs" always have 3 members : "positive", "negative", "zero."

So I want to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    MyClass() : signs({"positive", "negative", "zero"}) { }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> signs;
}
```

First of all, is this possible?

And Secondly, if it is possible, is this a recommended practice..?

Thanks

Comment: The latter initializes the variable once. It then assigns to the variable. For initializing a vector with a list, leave out the parentheses: `: signs{"positive", "negative", "zero"}`

Comment: Is this a recommended practice? I do not think so. Vector is a container that you use to store an arbitrary number of Objects. Lets say you have a Student Object, you will only need to create and Initialize your Vector once. Then use the same container to store an infinite number of Student. However, If you initialize your container in a constructor. Then every time you create a Student Object, you will also be initializing your current vector. Instead of just adding elements into it and increasing its current size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible<sup>*</sup>. You may omit the `()`:

```
MyClass() : signs{"positive", "negative", "zero"} { }
```

but you can also do the initialization at the point of declaration:

```
std::vector<std::string> signs{"positive", "negative", "zero"};
```

This has the advantage of setting initializing the vector in the same way in all constructors that do not explicitly initialize it.

Now, if the vector's elements are always the same, and if the vector will not be modified, you may consider making it a `static` member, so that you have one single instance shared by all instances of `MyClass`.

---

<sup>* unless you are stuck with a pre-C++11 compiler</sup>

Comment: Note that you'll need a very recent compiler for this to work correctly. I am stuck on Dev Studio 2010 and neither of these features work. But it's still the recommended way :)

Comment: @StilesCrisis Not *that* recent. 2010 was a long time ago ;-)

Comment: I don't think Dev Studio 2013 has everything here either. But I'm not using it day to day so I could be wrong.

Comment: @StilesCrisis It has been available with GCC since early 2012.

Comment: Yes, GCC and Clang have been championing C++11 much more strongly than Microsoft, much to my chagrin :|

Comment: @juanchopanza Considering that many professionals have to deal with older software and older operating systems, it's reasonable to say that you need a very recent compiler for this syntax. Even newer compilers, such as Visual Studio 2012, still doesn't have this feature.

Comment: @jliv902 I don't think that is relevant to this question. I am sure those professionals can figure it out, and if not, they can ask a VS or C++03 specific question. But I added a footnote.